# unwanted string pagespeed getting appended to imageurl making the images invisible on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a different behaviour i m observing in my webpages since when i started using pagespeed plugin in chrome browser.When ever i m calling ajax on checking any brand ,its appending some string in imageurls of images.which is making the images invisible,after checking the checkbox.Earlier whole code was working fine

following is my javascript sources,i didnt change them from start,but i suspect these files might got corrupted.Please check

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Please help,I m in a lot of trouble with this problem

The following string is getting appended in imageurls in end

```
pagespeed.ic.5k4QWZAfIK.jpg
```

Comment: Two jQuery references? That is wrong.

Comment: but when i reduce it to one i.e. the first one.then also its the same thing.I dont know whats wrong...

Comment: Hey Dude, First of all remove any of the jQuery initialization file. Why you put this twice? 1- from Google API and 2- From your server!?

Remove any one from your code.

Comment: i removed second one from my server.but still m getting this problem